# Windows 8, disabled UEFI but there is more trouble

Tags: installation, 12.10, partitioning, dell

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 12.10 on a new **dell inspiron 15z ultrabook**, that shipped with windows 8. When I boot from disc (with verified checksums) it works ok, and the `try ubuntu` button works, but when I go to install it crashes upon trying to view the partitions on the disc.

Is this related to the newish nature of Windows 8? I'm trying to decide if I need a different computer instead.

Comment: I think that the developer community is still testing a dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

A crash suggests a bug in libparted that's interacting with some sort of problem with the partition table. Try downloading and running the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and then post a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file that it produces. That will provide more information. You could also try running [gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) on the disk. (This will require installing the `gdisk` package -- but it's not readily installable from the Ubuntu live CD, so you might need to install manually or run a live CD like [Parted Magic,](http://partedmagic.com/) which includes `gdisk`.) Type `v` at the `gdisk` main menu; this performs a verification operation that may return clues if there's something obvious wrong with the partition table.